# How do I compute the following integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, expectation

$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left\{\frac{1}{2}\sin^{2}\left(tx\right)\right\} \phi\left(x\right)\, dx$ where $\phi$ is the density function of a standard normal distribution.

And also $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left\{\frac{1}{2}\cos^{2}\left(tx\right)\right\} \phi\left(x\right)\, dx$.

I've encountered this as the expectation of $\displaystyle \exp\left\{\frac{1}{2}\cos^{2}\left(tX\right)\right\}$ where $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. I'm sure this integral is finite but not sure if the result could be represented in a combination of elementary functions. How would I be able to know this and if there is closed form, how can I compute it?

Comment: presumably no closed form here

Comment: @tired oh... Seems like I'm out of luck.

Comment: you still can expand $\sin^2(tx) = (\frac{e^{itx}e^{-itx}}{2i})^2$ and $\exp(a e^{icx}) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a^k e^{ickx}}{k!}$ then integrate each obtained term of the form $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ibx} e^{-cx^2} dx$  which has closed form. or, you could try to use complex analysis, residue theorem, but not sure it is possible here